# Strapi - Media Library frontend side upload with user-specific access

Tags: upload, strapi

I want to let authorized end users (non-admin) upload images to the media library straight from frontend (with no view restrictions - just public after upload).

How can I let the user see only his own folder during upload? Can I create a folder with ID of the user? How to create a folder programmatically? Is it even possible? Or I gotta use Cloudinary or S3?

Comment: Could you make this?

Comment: @SalahAdDin, yes, you need to make a copy of a plugin and edit the controller and service by yourself

Comment: can you extend it from your Strapi project?

Comment: @SalahAdDin I added the answer, try and tell me if it works please

Answer (score 1):

To extend functionality of Strapi plugin we need to copy the needed plugin from `node_modules` to `src/extensions`

In this particular example, we just want to modify `add() a little

**src\extensions\upload\services\upload.js**

```
async add(values, { user } = {}) {
  const fileValues = { ...values };

  if (user) {
    fileValues[UPDATED_BY_ATTRIBUTE] = user.id;
    fileValues[CREATED_BY_ATTRIBUTE] = user.id;
    fileValues.username = user.username; // <<< Here
  }
  sendMediaMetrics(fileValues);

  const res = await strapi.query(FILE_MODEL_UID).create({ data: fileValues });

  await this.emitEvent(MEDIA_CREATE, res);

  return res;
},
```

Maybe it won't be enough, I just don't remember all the steps, but I think this would do the trick. If not - just go through the chain of invocations and make sure `user.username` at this stage is not `undefined` and it'll work.